# What does it mean to be in an advanced stage

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

I sent an email to a professor expressing my wish to be his student. He replied me that the selection is now "in a very advanced stage". He saw my application but hasn't got updated yet.

What does "in a very advanced stage" mean here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that they have a process that they go through to make the selection, and that the process is nearly complete.
A primary definition of *stage* is:

> a particular point or period in the growth or development of something <sub>[(m-w.com)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stage)</sub>

So, if you break the selection process into stages, the first stage might be "put all applicants into a list"; later stages might include "eliminate applicants whose grades on required courses are too low"; a final stage might be "flip a coin between the last two applicants".

An "advanced stage" is a step very near the end of the process, but not quite at the end.

Answer (score 0):

"Advanced" means "far on in time or course" [(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advanced). Selections being "in a very advanced stage" means that the professor is pretty far into the selection process. For example, if the process consists of several steps, such as (1) viewing applications, (2) choosing the best applications, (3) going through the narrowed field of applications, and (4) finally choosing students from that group, he may very well be on the third or fourth step.

Depending on exactly how far along in the process he is, he may not be accepting new applications any longer. You might want to email him back to check.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the professor has gone beyond the simple steps of looking through your resume, short-listing students etc; He might have limited seats for his class and those are almost full by now. He still might have to eliminate few from his list as the final step.

Jebakumar Eugene Asirvatham